# what does default_scope -> { kept } in rails means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am new to rails world. In one of the existing rails project I am working, I see a line in a model class as mentioned below. Can someone please tell me what does this signify. I tried searching documentation but couldn't find "kept" keyword anywhere.

`default_scope -> { kept }`

Comment: Can you send what your model look like where `default_scope` is defined?

Comment: My assumption is that `kept` is a scope on the model, hence asking to see your model definition

Comment: You can use `method(:kept).source_location` to attempt to see where its defined. This doesn't work for methods that are defined dynamically though such as through the `scope` macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I get, this is a scope that might be provided by a gem that allows you to "discard" records (instead of deleting them). The default scope is set to only return results that are kept (i. e. not discarded). Of course the functionality could also be developed manually but then you'd find the code in your project (e. g. in the model or a concern).

A popular gem to achieve this would be https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard (not affiliated with it) which effectively uses `kept`. Maybe check your Gemfile what gems your project uses and search their docs for this.

Comment: AKA soft delete.